# Execute php script after saving Joomla 3x form

Tags: php, joomla

How to execute a PHP script after saving a form data from Joomla 3x Banner component?

What I want to achieve is to run a push notification after saving ads in Joomla banner component. The push works well when I run it off Joomla platform, but I don't know where to place the code so that it can execute upon saving the form.

Comment: well I dont know which class method is called when Joomla is saving the form data for me to put the script there

Comment: This question has also been asked at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/18017/120

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the save method of the banner's model. Here's how you can override the model: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Once you override the model, you will need to modify the save method of the overridden file to suit your requirements.